# Terraform CIDR block for VPC not valid when using a variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cidr

I am trying to create a vpc as following:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "{$var.network_cidr}"
  tags {
    Name = "ECS_VPC"
  }
}
```

where `network_cidr` is defined in variables.tf file as

```
variable "network_cidr" {
  description = "IP addressing for the network"
}
```

and populated in terraform.tfvars as

```
network_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
```

When I try to run terraform apply `-var-file="terraform.tfvars"`

I get the following error :

```
Error: aws_vpc.vpc: "cidr_block" must contain a valid CIDR, got error
parsing: invalid CIDR address: {$var.network_cidr}
```

However if I hardcode the `cider_block = "10.0.0.0/16"` directly it works fine

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Comment: Do you have the terraform.tfvars file in the same directory where you run apply command?

Comment: You need to use `cidr_block = "${var.network_cidr}"` to interpolate the variable. Note the position of the dollar sign.

Comment: @Anuruddha yes I do indeed

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes you are right, I should have drank my coffee this morning :(

Comment: No worries, I've made sillier mistakes. I have voted to close as a typographic error.